# Oracle merge command error missing keyword

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-merge, ora-00905

I am trying to merge two tables in oracle and the query i am using is

```
merge into sales_history sh
 using sales s
 on (s.prod=sh.prod and s.month=sh.month)
 when matched 
      update set sh.amount = s.amount
 when not matched 
      insert (sh.prod,sh.month,sh.amount)
      values (s.prod,s.month,s.amount);
```

Whenever I execute this query i get the following error:

> ORA-00905 missing keyword.

Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: `when matched THEN update .... when not matched THEN ...`

Comment: yeah i spotted the error but thank you so much for answering :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 when matched 
      update set sh.amount = s.amount
 when not matched 
      insert (sh.prod,sh.month,sh.amount)
```

Your **MERGE** syntax is incorrect. You are missing the `THEN` keyword.

From the [**documentation**](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606):

**merge_update_clause ::=**

```
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE SET ...
```

**merge_insert_clause ::=**

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT
```